# Convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}\frac{\cos(e^n)}{n^3}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$\sum_{n=1}\frac{\cos(e^n)}{n^3}$

If n was equal to zero it would converge by the comparison criteria. It doesn't so I don't know. I tried using the ratio test but didn't work. Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ \left|\frac{\cos(e^n)}{n^3}\right|\leqslant\frac{1}{n^3} $$
and $\sum\frac{1}{n^3}$ converges thus the series $\sum\frac{\cos(e^n)}{n^3}$ converges.

Comment: Hold on... I thought that criteria could only be used when the series is always positive.

Comment: Couldn't I have divided the given series by 1/n^3 and calculated the limit?

Comment: Indeed but $\left|\frac{\cos(e^n)}{n^3}\right|\geqslant 0$ and thus the series $\sum\frac{\cos(e^n)}{n^3}$ is absolutely convergent. I don't understand what you mean by dividing the series by $\frac{1}{n^3}$ and calculating the limit.